# Croppie js Image Not Loading only In IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, croppie

I am using croppie js for loading image on my project, image loads fine in Chrome & Firefox.
This is What I Get on Chrome and Firefox

[image]

and this on  Internet Explorer 11.

[image]

Here is My code

```
var basic = $("#div" + selector).croppie({
         viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        },
        boundary: {
            width: widthContainer,
            height: 300
        },
        showZoomer: true,
        enforceBoundary:true
   });
 var bindPromise =  basic.croppie('bind', {
       url: path
       });

    $("#pnlcrop .cropcontainer div.croploader").remove();
    $("#div" + selector).show();
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why this issue is happening on IE11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the Issue By using `enableExif: true` and `exif.js`.

Here is  my Fixed code :

```
 $("#div" + selector).croppie('destroy');

    var basic = $("#div" + selector).croppie({
    enableExif: true,
         viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        },
        boundary: {
            width: widthContainer,
            height: 300
        },
        showZoomer: true,
        enforceBoundary:true
   });
 var bindPromise =  basic.croppie('bind', {
       url: path,
      });
```